# event after eav attribute save Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

I want to create an event observer when admin update attribute from admin panel. 
i've tried to `use eav_entity_attribute_save_afte`r and `eav_entity_attribute_delete_after`, but it's not working
I have not found any suitable event observer.
is in magento2 events for update eav attributes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `$productobj` after saving product from backend side so you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Right now you have to need develop new module for M2

Then Create this `events.xml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Create your observer file `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId(); //Get Product Id

        //Get Quantity
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockData = $stockItem->getQty();
        // Get new Qty
        $_vendor_qty = $product->getVendorQty();
        $_on_hand_qty = $product->getOnHandQty();
        $totalQty = $_vendor_qty+$_on_hand_qty; //Add New Qty


        $stockItem->setQty($totalQty); //Set New Qty to Main Qty
        $stockItem->save();

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try use afterSave plugin on Attribute ResourceModule instead

Comment: Do you have example?

Comment: You can see on \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags plugin that cleanup cache after entity is saved

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help **catalog_entity_attribute_save_before** / **catalog_entity_attribute_save_after**

### 1) Create **events.xml** inside Vendor/Module/etc/ and add below code inside events.xml

For **catalog_entity_attribute_save_before** Add This :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">   
    <event name="catalog_entity_attribute_save_before">
        <observer name="catalog_entity_attribute_save_before_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AttributeSaveBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

For **catalog_entity_attribute_save_after** Add This :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">   
    <event name="catalog_entity_attribute_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_entity_attribute_save_after_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AttributeSaveAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

### 2.1) For catalog_entity_attribute_save_after Create **AttributeSaveAfter.php** inside Vendor/Module/Observer/ and add below code inside AttributeSaveAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository as AttributeRepository;

class AttributeSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeRepository
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        AttributeRepository $repository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $config;
        $this->attributeRepository = $repository;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;

        $attrCode = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        if ($attrCode == 'your_attribute_code_for_compare') {

        }
    }
}
```

### 2.2) For catalog_entity_attribute_save_before Create **AttributeSaveBefore.php** inside Vendor/Module/Observer/ and add below code inside AttributeSaveBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository as AttributeRepository;

class AttributeSaveBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeRepository
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        AttributeRepository $repository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $config;
        $this->attributeRepository = $repository;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;

        $attrCode = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

        if ($attrCode == 'your_attribute_code_for_compare') {

        }
    }
}
```